# ERB doesn't recognize -%> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

When I run this line:

```
ERB.new("<%= 'hi' %>").result
```

It works fine and I get this output: `"hi"`

But when I run this line:

```
ERB.new("<%= 'hi' -%>").result
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: compile error
(erb):1: syntax error, unexpected ')'
_erbout = ''; _erbout.concat(( 'hi' -).to_s); _erbout
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set `trim_mode` parameter to `'-'`:

`ERB.new("<%= 'hi' -%>", nil, '-').result`

If using CLI, set it via `-T -`:

`erb -T - -r ./variables.rb template.erb`

Comment: Thanks, but will this preserve the functionality of the '-%>' tag?

Comment: Yes, see `ERB.new("<%= 'hi' -%>\nblah", nil, '-').result` vs. `ERB.new("<%= 'hi' %>\nblah", nil, '-').result`

Comment: Also, consider using [Haml](http://haml-lang.com). It's a generally superior alternative to ERb.

Comment: for CLI usage, one may set Trim Mode via `-T -`, like so `erb -T - -r './variables.rb' template.erb`